# issue with scroll

Tags: html, css

I had an issue with this scroll as in this image:

[image]

The issue is that I want only the vertical scroll to appear and not the horizontal scroll. I had used `overflow:scroll` attribute while coding. Will it look the same in Firefox and IE or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`.